# Running webpack as child process to generate source files

Tags: javascript, webpack, antlr, antlr4

I'm new to webpack so sorry if this is something obvious. I'm trying to get the package [`antlr4-webpack-loader`](https://github.com/tianyu/antlr4-webpack-loader) to work, generating some source code from a `.g4` file. I think I'm most of the way there, as I have a javascript file with `require` in it, and the `.bundle.` file seems to contain the output of antlr4, however it also has this:

```
module.exports = __webpack_require__(!(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module 'antlr4/index'"); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }()));
```

`contentScript.js` starts as below:

```
import 'jquery';
import 'antlr4'; // This line doesn't cause the error
import '../anaplan/AnaplanFormula.g4'; // This line causes the MODULE_NOT_FOUND error
```

`webpack.config.js` as below:

```
var webpack = require("webpack"),
path = require("path"),
fileSystem = require("fs"),
env = require("./utils/env"),
CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin").CleanWebpackPlugin,
CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin"),
HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin"),
WriteFilePlugin = require("write-file-webpack-plugin");

var options = {
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV || "development",
  entry: {
    contentScript: path.join(__dirname, "src", "js", "contentScript.js"),
    background: path.join(__dirname, "src", "js", "background.js"),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: "[name].bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: new RegExp('.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$'),
        loader: "file-loader?name=[name].[ext]",
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: "html-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.g4/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader:'antlr4-webpack-loader'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules']
  },
  node: { module: "empty", net: "empty", fs: "empty" },
  plugins: [
    // clean the build folder
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    // expose and write the allowed env vars on the compiled bundle
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(["NODE_ENV"]),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
      from: "src/manifest.json",
      transform: function (content, path) {
        // generates the manifest file using the package.json informations
        return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({
          description: process.env.npm_package_description,
          version: process.env.npm_package_version,
          ...JSON.parse(content.toString())
        }))
      }
    }]),
    new WriteFilePlugin(),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
    })
  ]
};

if (env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  options.devtool = "cheap-module-source-map";
}

module.exports = options;
```

From what I can tell the `antlr4-webpack-loader` plugin spawns a new webpack process for just the .g4 file and generates a bundle.js file from that as it's output, which then gets bundled into the 'parent' file. I can step through the code within `antlr4-webpack-loader` and that does appear to work (like I say, the output from it appears to be within my `contentScript.bundle.js` file. I can see it as something about `externals: [ 'antlr4/index' ],` which I guess is because the files it generates from the .g4 file require it, but the reference should get resolved by the script that required the g4.

For reference, `package.json` below which doesn't include the `antlr4` package in `devDependencies`, however I get the same error when i include it in both `devDependencies` and `dependencies`:

```
{
  "name": "anaplanextension",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "background.js",
  "directories": {
    "lib": "lib"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "antlr4": "^4.9.2",
    "arrive": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "antlr4-webpack-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "3.2.0",
    "file-loader": "4.3.0",
    "fs-extra": "8.1.0",
    "html-loader": "0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "style-loader": "1.0.0",
    "webpack": "4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.9.0",
    "write-file-webpack-plugin": "4.5.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node utils/build.js",
    "start": "node utils/webserver.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/georgeduckett/AnaplanExtension.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/georgeduckett/AnaplanExtension/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/georgeduckett/AnaplanExtension#readme"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to go a different route here. That webpack loader has not been updated in the last 4 years, uses a pretty old ANTLR4 jar (current version is 4.9.2) and uses the Javascript runtime, which is known for certain problems.

Instead I recommend that you switch to the [antlr4ts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/antlr4ts) runtime and use [antlr4ts-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/antlr4ts-cli) to generate your files from the grammar. Both are still marked as being alpha, but I have used these packages for years already (e.g. in my vscode extension [vscode-antlr4](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mike-lischke.vscode-antlr4)).

With that in place you can remove the webpack loader and generate the parser/lexer files as part of your build process.